# Undefined Variable and Function prepare() on null

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to create a page where it will output the usernames of my database. While doing so, I have two errors saying *"Undefined variable: conn in functions.php"* and *"Call to a member function prepare() on null in functions.php"*.

**functions.php** - *Line 6 is the error*

```
<?php 

require 'database.php';

function getUser($id, $field) {
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT $field FROM users WHERE id='$id'"); //error line
    $query->bind_param($id, $field);
    $query->execute();
    $run = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $run[$field];
}

?>
```

**database.php**

```
<?php

// 3 variables below removed 
$dsn = ''; 
$username = '';
$password = '';

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection denied: " . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

**members.php**

```
<?php 

    require 'functions.php';
    require 'database.php';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM users');
    $stmt->execute();

    while($run_mem = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $user_id = $run_mem['id'];
        $usernames = getUser($user_id, 'username');
        echo $usernames;

    }   

?>
```

The error is not showing up on members.php on the prepare() statement even though I am using the same variable *$conn*.

Would greatly appreciate if a solution is found!

Comment: [Variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: How does `$conn` get into the function?

Comment: Thank you @AbraCadaver I just cut and paste require 'database.php'; to inside that function

Answer (score 0):

you have a variable scope issue,

to solve this you can pass the `$conn` variable as a parameter to the function at the function declaration step as follows:

```
function getUser($conn, $id, $field) {
```

then when you going to call your function, pass the connection variable as follows:

```
$usernames = getUser($conn, $user_id, 'username');
```